# How do I disable auto string escape in Firefox's developer console?

Tags: javascript, firefox, console

Coming from Chrome, I'm used to the following producing a non escaped string in the developer JS console:

```
> JSON.stringify(JSON.parse('{"a": 10}'))
{"a":10}
```

​However, in Firefox, it produces the following:

```
> JSON.stringify(JSON.parse('{"a": 10}'))
"{\"a\":10}"   <-- notice that the quote has been escaped as \", which is correct, but not what I want
```

​How can I instruct Firefox to stop escaping the strings printed in the JS console?

Comment: I don't think there is a setting, unfortunately. You could just wrap it in a console.log()? What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply use console.log() like this:

`> console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.parse('{"a":10}')))`
`{"a":10}`

Cheers!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!